# ExtJS 4 / Sencha Touch Container, Component, Element and Panel

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs4, extjs

What are the relations or differences between Container, Component, Element and Panel?

Please help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If briefly...

**Element** is wrapper for DOM element.

**Component** is basic class for all widgets.

**Container** is subclass of Component. It can have "items" (i.e. Container can contain other components).

**Panel** is subclass of Container. It can have header, footer, toolbars, and other docked items.

You can find more info in [Layouts & Containers](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/layouts_and_containers) and [Components](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/components)

Answer (score 2):

For Sencha Touch, Container and Panel are currently (as of 2.0 beta) the same except for 3 attributes that are deprecated.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Panel

They are essentially interchangeable.  This may change in the future to match up closer to Ext 4.0 where a Panel has footers, headers and toolbars while a container doesn't.