# Comparison of Ext.Component And Ext.Container

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

Can anybody make me clear that how does `Ext.Component` and `Ext.Container` differ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question has already been addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722520/extjs-4-sencha-touch-container-component-element-and-panel

Answer (score 0):

Ext.Container can contain other components and layout them with defined layout.